# How to display list.phtml categories product in view.phtml file.

Tags: magento-1.7, magento-1.8, product-list, static-block, product-view

We have tried to display static block in view.phtml file.
But, does not showing static block content in view.phtml file.
I thinks because i have to showing 
categories product display in view.phtml file.

We have added following code in static block (block_footer_items_product_detail_page).

```
{{block type="catalog/product_list" category_id="193" name="product_list"  count="3" limit="4"  template="catalog/product/list.phtml"}}
```

And print static block in view.phtml file as below code

```
<?php echo $this->getLayout()->createBlock('cms/block')->setBlockId('block_footer_items_product_detail_page')->toHtml();?>
```

Does not showing product lists item in product view(detail) page.

I have need to display product lists above static block print category product in view.phtml file.

Simple, I want to list.phtml file product display into footer side in view.phtml file.

Thanks

Comment: You'll need to dig around Stackoverflow's magento QAs, as I recall various answers concerning showing "content" in other areas. Mostly this is about getting the "collection" you need in the location your code is.

Comment: Please provide debugging info (e.g. is the category instantiated?) and update.